# Application not loading in Ubuntu 18.04, NGINX, Passenger configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed NGINX and Passenger on Ubuntu 18.04 and am having issues getting any meaningful indication of what's wrong with my configuration.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
http {
    # pretty much the default configuration except for this...
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app** (this is a symlink to sites-available)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.app.ip.address;

  root /path/to/public/folder;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_root /path/to/app/root; # not public folder
  passenger_ruby /home/appuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/wrappers/ruby;

  rails_env staging;

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }
}
```

**Results of `systemctl status nginx`**
[image]

**Results of `passenger-status`**
[image]

**Output of `/var/log/nginx/error.log`**
[image]

When I try to access the IP address via a web browser, it refuses to connect and suggests I check the connection and firewall. Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `passenger_app_root`. That directive is for where passenger is, not the root of your app.

If you're using the standard RoR layout where public is a subfolder of the application root, you don't need to specify anything, but if they really are completely different than the directive you're looking for is [passenger_root](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_root), which configures the root of your application.

Comment: Thanks, @mindlace. Unfortunately, removing `passenger_app_root` and restarting nginx didn't work. Same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: And actually, the documentation seems to indicate `root` is the root of the app, `passenger_root` is for the Passenger root directory (or config file), and `passenger_app_root` specifies the application's root directory (by default it assumes the parent directory of the `root` declaration).

Comment: I noticed that going to my IP address automatically tried to reconcile to https, so adding `listen 443 ssl;` and a temporary self-signed cert fixed it.